# FInd a particular Record from more than 2 Tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 5 to 6 tables in my Database in Sql. I want to find a particular record form those table (eg: welcome dept) I am not aware in which table and which column it is in.

I have 3 tables (Customer_table,Employee_table,Workers_Table) in this I have to search a name (aaa) in all this 3 tables.

How can I write a SQL query?

Comment: `How can I write a SQL query` ... _you_ need to tell us the search criteria and what you have already tried.

Comment: Why don't you know where you store your data? Anyway, if this is a one-time issue, simply write 5 or 6 queries to search you tables.

Comment: I am using SQL server. assume I have 3 tables (Customer_table,Employee_table,Workers_Table) in this I have to search a name (aaa) in all this 3 tables

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided much info... so here's my untested guess:

```
SELECT name
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM Customer_table WHERE name = 'aaa';
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Employee_table WHERE name = 'aaa';
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Workers_Table WHERE name = 'aaa';
    UNION ALL
) tbl
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(*) = 1
```